# need a shell script to change the comma delimiter to a pipe delimeter

Tags: shell, delimiter

My input looks like `"$130.00","$2,200.00","$1,230.63"` and so on
My question is how can I go about changing the comma delimiter to a | delimiter without getting rid of the comma in the actual input. 
Just to clarify this input is in a csv file with 40 columns and 9500 rows.
I want my output to look like

```
"$130.00"|"$2,200.00"|"$1,230.63"
```

Comment: Does the program importing the file not know how to deal with embedded commas properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this reliably, you have to use states to keep track of wether you are inside a string or not. The following perl script should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $state_outside_string = 0;
my $state_inside_string  = 1;

my $state = $state_outside_string;

while (my $line = <>) {
    my @chars = split(//,$line);
    foreach my $char (@chars) {
        if ($char eq '"') {
            if ($state == $state_outside_string) {
                $state = $state_inside_string;
            } else {
                $state = $state_outside_string;
            }
        } elsif ($char eq ',') {
            if ($state == $state_outside_string) {
                print '|';
                next;
            }
        }
        print $char;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it worked but for some reason my awk script won't parse through the columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other commas in your file, you can use:

```
sed "s/,/|/g" filename > outputfilename
```

If the commas are only between the `""`s, then:

```
sed 's/","/"|"/g' filename > outputfilename
```

Works like this:

```
sh-3.1$ echo '"123,456","123,454"' |sed 's/","/"|"/g'
"123,456"|"123,454"
```

If you can still have an quoted-expression like `","` in your input and don't want to change that, then it gets a bit more complicated, I think :)

---

Another solution with Python using a dedicated module, probably best in terms of safety and code needed:

```
import csv
inFilename = 'input.csv'
outFilename = 'output.csv'

r = csv.reader(open(inFilename))
w = csv.writer(open(outFilename,'w'), delimiter='|', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
w.writerows(list(r))
```

Safe and simple. You can tweak this for other formats easily, the parameters are fairly straightforward.

Comment: the problem with this is that I still have rows of commas to split up blank columns and sed command there won't change them.

Comment: OK, in that case here's a complete solution in Python (edited) in case you need another one :D

Answer (score 1):

Does 'having shell run a Perl script' count?

If so, I'd look at Perl's [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) module.  You'd have two CSV handles, one for reading the file with the `sep_char` attribute set as comma (the standard, default), the other for writing the file with the `sep_char` attribute set as pipe.

### Working script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

die "Usage: $0 in_file out_file\n" unless scalar @ARGV == 2;
my $in  = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, blank_is_undef => 1 })
    or die "Horribly";
my $out = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, sep_char => '|',
                           always_quote => 1, eol => "\n" })
    or die "Horribly";
open my $fh_in,  '<', $ARGV[0]
    or die "Failed to open $ARGV[0] for reading ($!)";
open my $fh_out, '>', $ARGV[1]
    or die "Failed to open $ARGV[1] for writing ($!)";

while (my $fields  = $in->getline($fh_in))
{
    $out->print($fh_out, $fields);
}

close $fh_in  or die "Failed to close input ($!)";
close $fh_out or die "Failed to close output ($!)";
```

#### Sample input

```
"$130.00","$2,200.00","$1,230.63"
"EUR1.300,00",,
"GBP1,300.00","$2,200.00",
```

#### Sample output

```
"$130.00"|"$2,200.00"|"$1,230.63"
"EUR1.300,00"||
"GBP1,300.00"|"$2,200.00"|
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's CSV library was replaced with [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) in 1.9; in earlier versions you can use the `fastercsv` gem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "csv"

output = CSV.read("test.csv").map do |row|
  row.to_csv(:col_sep => "|")
end
puts output
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue I did not any perfect solution so I tried as below:

```
for file in `find $1 -name "*.csv"`
        do
            extension=`echo $file | awk -F . '{print $NF}'`
            fileName=`basename $file .csv`
            cat $file | awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "~", $i) } 1' > "$fileName.txt"
            cat "$fileName.txt" | sed 's/,/|/g' > pipedelimited.txt
            cat pipedelimited.txt | sed 's/~/,/g' > "$fileName.txt"
            rm -rf pipedelimited.txt
            echo "File Convert is complted for $file"
done
```

This will create pipe-delimited files for all files under the directory passed to the shell script. This also handles the escape character which is having extra comma in a column.